# Proving Logical Equivalances

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have been trying to prove that these two  logical statements are equivalent using only standard logic equivalence transformations.

(p ∧ q) → r and (p → r) ∨ (q → r)

The following is my working however I'm certain I have made an error somewhere.

(p ∧ q) → r and (p → r) ∨ (q → r)

(p ∧ q) → r and (¬(p → ¬r)) ∨ (¬(q ∧ ¬r)

(p ∧ q) → r and (¬(p ∨ q)) ∧ ¬r)

¬(p ∧ q) ∨ r and (¬(p ∨ q)) ∧ ¬r)

¬p ∨ ¬q) ∨ r and (¬(p ∨ q)) ∧ ¬r)

¬(p ∨ q) → ¬r and ¬(p ∧ q) ∨ r

Comment: Second step wrong.

Comment: It must be $(\lnot p \lor r) \lor (\lnot q \lor r)$

Comment: I see I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

$a\to b$ is equivalent to $(\neg a)\vee b$. So $(p\to r)\vee(q\to r)$ is equivalent to $((\neg p)\vee r)\vee((\neg q)\vee r)$, which is equivalent to $(\neg p)\vee(\neg q)\vee r$. You've already shown that the other expression is equivalent to this.